# How can I delete this Specific node from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, togglebutton

I have created a Like button in the App. When user click on the Like Button a Node called "Like Posts" with a child (random Key) is created where the details of the posts are saved as you can see in the Image.
But, when i click on the Like button again, the node should get removed as per standards. But, that's not happening.

[image]

This is my code :

```
 holder.fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



                String id = likesReference.push().getKey();
                 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Liked Posts").child(id).removeValue();



                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from Favorites !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {



                likesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Liked Posts");

                Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Bookmarks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                likesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        HomeModel homeModel1 = new HomeModel(holder.newsTitleTextView.getText().toString().trim(), holder.newsDetailTextView.getText().toString().trim(),
                                holder.timesAgo.getText().toString().trim(), homeModel.getNewsImage(), homeModel.viewCounts);

                        String id = likesReference.push().getKey();

                        Log.e("KEY IS", id);  //right one

                        likesReference.child(id).setValue(homeModel1);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }
```

How to delete the "Liked Posts" ?

Comment: please keep your code sample minimal. there is a lot of code in your sample that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Is the `-M903...ca_p` in the screenshot the ID of the post the user liked? If not, how do you know what post they liked?

Comment: Yes sir, it is the Field, As the user liked the posts, an entry is made to their respective account and the toggle button is turned on which indicates the user has liked the post

Comment: So you want to remove only the `-M903...ca_p` or the entire `Liked Posts` node?

Comment: only the - M903... posts sir

Comment: @AlexMamo Sir, are you there ?

Comment: To send a message to a specific user always use `@`. Have you stored somewhere that id (`-M903...ca_p`)?

Comment: im not sending any message. just want to delete this node